# como desfazer "git checkout" de um commit especifico e voltar para o ultimo commit que fiz antes do checkout

Tags: git, bitbucket

Preciso voltar para o ambiente que estava antes de eu realizar *git checkout id_commit* porém quando eu executo *git log* não aparecem mais os *commits* que realizei depois do *checkout*. No repositório remoto aparecem todos os *push* que eu dei, tem como eu deixar o repósitório local igual ao repósitório remoto e voltar para o último commit que eu dei?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Experimente usar `git reflog`. Você deve ter uma listagem como:

```
220981e HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to 220981e
239b47a HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from c_api to master
```

isso indica que no último checkout eu estava no branch `master` fui para o commit 220981e. Para voltar onde eu estava.

```
git checkout master
```

Comment: eu queria voltar para *e655486 HEAD@{3}: commit: voltando no commit em que eu estava fazendo o pdf via PHP* tem como? eu dei *git checkout master* mas ainda não consegui voltar para o ambiente que eu tava antes